# Cast char* to int

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

I am writing some code to get a hex dump of the stack in c. I keep getting a compile error on this following line when I compile it using gcc in ubuntu however it compiles fine under gcc in windows.

```
char buffer[10];
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("0x%lx => 0x%lx\n", &(buffer[i]), ((long *)buffer)[i]);
```

This is the message the compiler gives.

> warning: format ‘%lx’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’

Can someone please tell me if I am doing someting wrong?

Comment: The compiler pretty much tells you what you're doing wrong. And also everything is undefined behaviour :-(

Comment: You are also accessing unallocated memory, especially accessing the buffer as `long` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
char buffer[10];
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    printf("%p => 0x%lx\n", (void*)&(buffer[i]), ((long *)buffer)[i]);
```

The 2nd arg, `&(buffer[i])` is of type `char*`, so it needs a cast and a `%p`.

The 3rd arg, `((long *)buffer)[i]`, is of type `long`, so it needs a `%lx`.

---

*Aside*: Please realize that if `buffer` is not `long`-aligned, you might get the right answer, the wrong answer, or a core dump, all depending upon your CPU, OS, OS settings, and/or compiler.

If it were *me*, I'd try:

```
long l;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("%p => 0x%lx\n", (void*)(&l+i), *(&l+i));
```

Comment: `%p` requires a `void*`, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `%p` to print pointers, and remember to cast to `void *`.

```
printf("%p => ??\n", (void *)&(buffer[i]), ...);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you're trying to interpret a portion of `buffer` as a long and print it than you can use `%ld`.

Comment: The problem is not with printing the pointer, it's dereferencing the cast. The second argument causes the compile error.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm not sure actually. The warning however was caused by "*argument 2*".

Comment: @cnic my apologies, I've been interpreting the second argument to mean the second argument excluding the string. ooops